# NullPointerException when calling a Fragment method from Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when calling a Fragment's method.

In my **MainActivity:**

```
  AddTab fragObj = (AddTab) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_add);
 fragObj.receiveURL(sharedText);
```

receiveURL() is a method in my Fragment AddTab.

I'm using `pagerslidingtabstrip` in my app to create tabs and that `Fragment` is created by it's `PagerAdapter` class.

I'm not sure if it is right to create a new instance of the Tab, because already one exists. I don't know how to get access to that instance as well.

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` now. Can anyone please help me on how to call that method in the fragment?

**EDIT :**

**AddTab.java :**

```
public class AddTab extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
```

...

}

**fragment_add.xml :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.nikhil.amazon1.Add">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="@string/URL"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Track"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I doubt your fragment id really is R.layout.fragment_add ... are you using the add method to add fragment dynamically ?

Comment: oops!  That is the layout of my fragment, I didn't find anything, so I supposed it to be id. Am I wrong?

Comment: See if my answer helps you. I'm not quite sure what the result would be of using findFragmentById or findFragmentByTag in combination with a ViewPager. If you decide to give it a try, please do let me know if it works for you, I'd be interested to know... If indeed it returns something, I suggest checking if Fragment is visible before touching its UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `<fragment>` tag to include a `Fragment` in your layout, you can use find `findFragmentById` using the id you assigned for the `Fragment` in the xml. Example :

```
<fragment
    ...
    android:id="@+id/fragment_id/>
```

and

```
AddTab fragObj = (AddTab)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
```

If you added your `Fragment` dynamically, use tags :

```
String TAG = "fragment tag";

FragmentTransaction ft;
ft.add(containerViewId, fragment, TAG);
```

and

```
AddTab fragObj = (AddTab)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @2Dee. But, It seems like I don't have a <fragment>   in my XML as you can see in the question. I have a <framelayout>

Comment: The framelayout is in your fragment layout, fragment tags are usually included in the activity layout, so I was referring to a fragment added in the XML of the activity (mainly to help others viewing this question). Note that I also provide a method to get the fragment added dynamically using FragmentTransaction.